# PHP/MYSQL group and count by distinct dates and users

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to get a distinct count of days a user logged in, when the db has each login session stored with a time and date stamp (DATETIME column). EG:

```
USERID | TIME | BOUGHT  
--------------------------
4 | 2012-07-16 04:44:52   | 3
4 | 2012-07-16 04:45:52   | 2  
5 | 2012-07-16 04:54:52   | 5
4 | 2012-07-18 04:44:52   | 3
4 | 2012-07-18 04:45:52   | 2  
4 | 2012-07-21 04:54:52   | 5
```

I want to search for how many times user 4 bought from the site - and the query should return 3 (because user 4 visited the site a total of 3 days). Do I have to use a PHP/MYSQL combination or can I do it in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT USERID, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(TIME)) FROM my_table GROUP BY USERID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8988b/1/0).

Comment: But how do I do it when I'm searching for user 4 (eg I want to see how many days user 4 bought something?)

Comment: [`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(TIME)) FROM my_table WHERE USERID = 4`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8988b/4/0).